# Can an analytic function on the open unit disk blow up near the boundary?

Tags: complex-analysis

Can we have a map $f$, holomorphic on the open unit disk, such that $|f(z)|\rightarrow \infty$ as $|z|\rightarrow 1$? I think not, (at least I can't think of any such map), but I'd like to be able to prove this.

Comment: Do you mean as $|z|\rightarrow 1$?  1/(z-1) blows up at one point, do you need it to blow up at all boundary points?

Comment: To blow up at all boundary points consider the answer to [this post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10831/example-of-continuous-function-that-is-analytic-on-the-interior-but-cannot-be-an)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such a function cannot exist. Suppose such a function exists. Let $z_1,\ldots,z_k$ be the zeros of $f$ in the unit disc with corresponding multiplicites $m_1,\ldots,m_k$. Then
$$g(z) = \frac{(z - z_1)^{m_1}\cdots(z - z_n)^{m_k}}{f(z)}$$
is an analytic function in the unit disc such that $\lim_{\vert z \vert \to 1}g(z) = 0$. This contradicts the maximum modulus principle.

Comment: Note that we don't have $\lim\limits_{\lvert z\rvert \to 1} \lvert f(z)\rvert = +\infty$. That is not possible for holomorphic functions on the unit disk. Also, the denseness of dyadic rationals doesn't prove that the radial limit is $\infty$ at other points.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Why is it not possible to have holomorphic function that blows up at all boundary points?

Comment: @Curious See the edited answer. Such a function could have only finitely many zeros, and dividing those out would leave a zero-free holomorphic function that still blows up at all boundary points (since the domain is bounded). Then its reciprocal would violate the maximum modulus principle.

Comment: @DanielFischer Excellent, thanks!